# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 23 Out of resources when opening file xxxx.MYD' (Errcode: 24)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, memory

I am getting this error message when trying to access a php page:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 23 Out of resources when opening file xxxx.MYD' (Errcode: 24)
```

How can I solve this issue?
How can I determine the lacking resource? Memory, processor or file space?

PS: Meanwhile I noticed the log has these warnings

```
160111 13:15:26 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024

160111 13:12:25 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't open file: './xxxxx/cache_path.frm' (errno: 24)
```